# Android - Kotlin - Prepoluate room database

Tags: android, database, kotlin, android-room

I am stuck for 4 days on the same issue so I hope getting some help hear.
I am trying to load data to a database  through an SQL script but often when I run the app for the first time I have an error :

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{small.app.beeroclock/small.app.beeroclock.MainActivity}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Pre-packaged database has an invalid schema: Country(small.app.beeroclock.db.Country).
     Expected:
    TableInfo{name='Country', columns={country_name=Column{name='country_name', type='TEXT', affinity='2', notNull=true, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='null'}, country_code=Column{name='country_code', type='TEXT', affinity='2', notNull=true, primaryKeyPosition=1, defaultValue='null'}}, foreignKeys=[], indices=[Index{name='index_Country_country_code', unique=false, columns=[country_code]}]}
     Found:
    TableInfo{name='Country', columns={}, foreignKeys=[], indices=[]}
```

Thing is I don't undestand the Pre-packaged database has an invalid schema cause my database is based on the Entities :

```
@Entity
data class City(
    @NotNull
    @PrimaryKey
    val name: String,
    @NotNull
    val lat: Double,
    @NotNull
    val lng: Double,
    @NotNull
    val country_code: String
) {
}
```

And here the the appdatabase class :

```
@Database(
    entities = arrayOf(Country::class, Timezone::class, Zone::class, City::class),
    version = 1
)


abstract class AppDatabase : RoomDatabase() {
    abstract fun countryDAO(): CountryDAO
    abstract fun timezoneDAO(): TimezoneDAO
    abstract fun zoneDAO(): ZoneDAO
    abstract fun cityDAO(): CityDAO

}

lateinit var _context: Context

@Volatile
private lateinit var INSTANCE: AppDatabase
fun getInstance(context: Context): AppDatabase {
    synchronized(AppDatabase::class.java) {
        if (!::INSTANCE.isInitialized) {
            _context = context
            INSTANCE = Room.databaseBuilder(
                context.applicationContext,
                AppDatabase::class.java,
                "app_database"
            ).addCallback(rdc).fallbackToDestructiveMigration()
                .build()
            //.addCallback(rdc)
        }
        return INSTANCE;
    }
}

var rdc: RoomDatabase.Callback = object : RoomDatabase.Callback() {
    override fun onCreate(db: SupportSQLiteDatabase) {
        super.onCreate(db)
        //INSERT INTO `country` VALUES ('AF','Afghanistan')
//TODO : Issue to insert cities
        try {
            db.beginTransaction()
            _context.assets.open("sql/timezonedb.sql").bufferedReader().forEachLine {
                db.execSQL(it)
            }
            db.setTransactionSuccessful();
            Log.d("Callback", "The creation of the db is done")
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            e.printStackTrace()
            Log.d("Callback", "Issue with the database import")
        } finally {
            db.endTransaction();
        }

    }


    override fun onOpen(db: SupportSQLiteDatabase) {
    }
}
```

I guess it is not coming from the sql file itself because if, so I would have a sql error.

If anyone can highlight me I would really appreciate that :D

Regardss

Comment: You are packaging SQL statements, not a database. It would be simpler to write and faster for users if you packaged an actual database and used `createFromAsset()`. See [this sample project](https://gitlab.com/commonsguy/cw-room/-/tree/v0.3/PackagedFTS) (covered in [this book](https://commonsware.com/Room)).

Comment: I wanted to but didn't find an easy way to get a db file. I will look into your link thx.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok I figure a way to do what I want but I think it not that easy (for new bee of db like me).

So to anyone with the same issue this I how I proceed.

First export the schema of the db using :
exportSchema property in the db class

```
@Database(
    entities = arrayOf(Country::class, Timezone::class, Zone::class, City::class),
    version = 1,
    exportSchema = true
)
```

And adding the needed properties in the gradle module file :

```
apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'


android {
    .....
    defaultConfig {
       ......
        kapt {
            arguments {
                arg("room.schemaLocation", "$projectDir/schemas")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

After rebuilding the project you should get a json file under ../app/schema
This JSON file contain all you need to create a db in sql.
I extract the "createSql" line and replace the ${TABLE_NAME} by the real name :

```
"tableName": "Country",
        "createSql": "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `${TABLE_NAME}` (`country_code` TEXT NOT NULL, `country_name` TEXT NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY(`country_code`))",
```

become :

```
createSql": "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `Country` (`country_code` TEXT NOT NULL, `country_name` TEXT NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY(`country_code`));
```

So with those queries I created a SQL file.

Now to get a db file I use DB browser by SQLite : https://sqlitebrowser.org/

From there I created a new db file and run the sql file in it.

Finally, I added the db file to my android project under the assets folder (create a new one if you have none) and add the command in the db builder to create from a db file :

```
.createFromAsset("fileName.db")
```

Please leave comment if not clear.

Regards

Comment: Any chance you could post a sample project to github? I found this while trying to figure out how to include an SQLite db as a beginner, and all the tutorials I have read so far give me projects that dont run on the emulator.

Comment: Hello, sure  : https://github.com/moutyque/BeerOClock
 if you have more question leave a comment.

Answer (score 1):

For any developers having the same issue in 2023 and having trouble exporting their DB schema. To get the .db file you can

- Run the project on an emulator with API 26 or better
- Go to the "App Inspection" tab (choose the "Database Inspector" section)
- Right-click on the database you want to export
- Choose "Export as File"
- Make sure "DB" is the selected File Type and hit export

Then to modified the file I used the DB browser by SQLite: https://sqlitebrowser.org/

- Open DB Browser
- Click open database and choose the .db file you just exported
- Go to execute SQL tab to run any updates
- Click Write Changes
- Copy the .db file to the assets folder in your android project
- Add a ".createFromAsset("databaseFile.db") call when you create the database

```
Room.databaseBuilder(context, AppDatabase::class.java, "app_database")
   .createFromAsset("databaseFile.db")
   .build()
```

Official documentation on prepopulating the database https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room/prepopulate